# How to subscribe to changes by field within a single document

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to figure out the correct pattern for subscribing to specific changes within a single document.  An example will better highlight what I'm trying to do.  Say, I have a Mongo document for a blog post, which in turn contains a list of comments.  Right now, I have a query to find that blog post: `Posts.findOne("<id">)`, which reactively updates my template:

```
<template name="post">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    {{#each comments}}
        {{> comment this}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

The issue is that when anything changes at all about that post (generally the comments list as people add them), everyone who's viewing that post will have the whole thing refresh.  I'd rather 1) setup some sort of listener that's field specific, and/or 2) do a bit of manual intercepting to say "when post updates, check to see what's updated, and update something dependent on what's changed (e.g. only update the comment that's been updated, or, looks like there's a new record - let's add it)".

I know this sort of thing is doable at the document level using `Collection.observe` (e.g. as new documents come and go, you have granular control to see what changed), but what about within documents?  I think I could do it by storing my current document in a Session, and then when the document updates and I'm notified by reactive find command, compare new document to old one, but is that the best way?  Am I missing something obvious?

Any guidance is much appreciated!

Comment: Can I ask why it is any issue that the whole post redraws?

Comment: The blog post/comment example is just a simple version of what I'm doing.  Maybe a closer example to what I'm actually doing would be google docs.  People are editing the same document (well, various regions/pieces of that document) and I want to patch in changes to the document, instead of completely refreshing the whole thing each time there's any change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning Meteor as well (a few weeks into it) and had an issue like the one you describe. My suggestion at this time would be that you have your app subscribe to **2** collections: **Posts** and **Comments**.

A *Comments* item could look like this:

```
{
  _id    :  \\ auto-generated ID by Mongo,
  text   : 'this is the comment',
  PostID : 'postUniqueID'
  user   : 'username'
  //etc. 
}
```

On the client-side, in your *Comments* subscription, you pass as a parameter the unique ID of the post. On the server-side, you only publish the Comments where PostID = *postUniqueID*.

**Important**: You'd need to set your *Comments* subscription in a Meteor.autorun() block, such that it changes whenever the user switches to another blog post.

In my experience, this approach makes your templating and coding much simpler. However, I haven't analyzed if subscribing to two collections (versus one) has a noticeable effect on Meteor's performance.